# Bracket checking function only tests first 2 entered?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have encountered a bit of a mental problem in implementing this function. It should be able to make sure all brackets are entered correctly such as: ()[] is true and [({}[])] is true but [[] would be false. I have to use the stack within this function, yet for some reason it compared 2 brackets correctly but anything entered beyond 2 it won't work. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code:

function.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"stack.h"
using std::string;


bool bracketCheck(const string& s) {

    Stack<char> stack;

    if (!s.empty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '[') {
                            stack.push(s[i]);
                    }
                    else if (s[i] == ')' && stack.top() == '(' || s[i] == '}' && stack.top() == '(' || s[i] == ']' && stack.top() == '['){
                            stack.pop();
                    }
            }
            return stack.isEmpty() ? true : false;
    }
}
```

stack.h :

```
template <typename T>
class Stack{
T* theStack_;
int max_;
int size_;
void grow(){
    T* tmp=new T[max_*2];
    for(int i=0;i<size_;i++){
        tmp[i]=theStack_[i];
    }
    max_=max_*2;
    delete [] theStack_;
    theStack_=tmp;
}
public:
Stack(){
    theStack_=new T[50];
    max_=50;
    size_=0;
}
void push (const T& data){
    if(size_==max_){
        grow();
    }
    theStack_[size_]=data;
    size_++;
}
void pop(){
    if(!isEmpty()){
        size_--;
    }
}
//removed top() const
T top()  {
    if(!isEmpty()){
        return theStack_[size_-1];
    }
    return T{};
}
bool isEmpty(){
    return size_==0;
}
~Stack(){
    delete [] theStack_;
}
};
```

main :

```
int main()
{
    string expression;

    cout << "Enter an expression:  ";
    cin >> expression;
    if (bracketCheck(expression))
            cout << "Balanced\n";
    else
            cout << "Not Balanced\n";
}
```

for instance: it comes out as saying (] is not balanced but ()] is balanced.

Comment: Your rather long boolean condition in your `else-if` needs some "bracketing": of its own. Mixing `&&` and `||` may not be doing what you think it is. Be *specific* in your conditional expressions, and don't fear throwing parens around them.

Comment: `bracketCheck` has paths that do not have a `return` statement. This means the program is invalid and the compiler is allowed generate code that does anything it wants.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is in this line of code:

```
if (s[i] == ')' && stack.top() == '(' || s[i] == '}' && stack.top() == '(' || s[i] == ']' && stack.top() == '[')
```

Where you need to "group" your conditions like this:

```
if ((s[i] == ')' && stack.top() == '(') || (s[i] == '}' && stack.top() == '{') || (s[i] == ']' && stack.top() == '['))
```

Also notice the `{` typo fix.

Comment: I changed it to the above.... but it still says ()) is balanced for example

Comment: is it a problem in main maybe?

Comment: Did you step through your code? If you are on Visual Studio then use F-10 and see where does your code vary from your expectations.

Comment: seems as long as first 2 brackets meet condition it just won't test for more against the condition

Comment: Why when you `pop()` you don't remove the character from your array?

Comment: what do you mean? wouldn't the pop call be moving the char if they match?

Comment: if it is last in the stack